# Locking on a primitive type

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to check some locking behaviors and i can't understand this :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            MultithreadedMethod();
        });
    }

    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    Console.WriteLine(count);
}

static int count = 0;
private static readonly int sync = 5;

public static void MultithreadedMethod()
{
    if (Monitor.TryEnter(sync))
    {
        count++;
        Monitor.Exit(sync);
    }
}
```

I thought that this should not work due to the fact i am doing the synchronization on an integer value. First Boxing, then Unboxing and i should get a System.Threading.SynchronizationLockException because of the missing sync block root ( i know this is specific to reference types ).
I am not going to fool myself, even if this works for a few iterations, it's not really synchronized.. so, taking into consideration the non atomic property of the increment operation .. i will not get deterministic results.. i am aware of this.

Indeed, when i get rid of that Thead.Sleep and put a Wait on the Task.. the exception comes into place.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
 {
       MultithreadedMethod();
 }).Wait();
```

I think an exception should be thrown here : `Monitor.Exit(sync)`

but what catches it?

**Update 1: pic added.**

[image]

Comment: When I run the above code it does throw an exception from `Exit`. Sure you are capturing the exception from the task?

Comment: @PatrickHofman this is all i have. Just made the pic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but what catches it?

The exception thrown inside a `Task` object is implicitly captured inside that `Task`. Unless you access the `Task.Exception` or `Task.Wait/Task.Result` properties, or `await` on the returned task, the exception would be swallowed and you won't be able to see it. That is why using `Wait` propagates the exception and you can see it in the console. Same will happen if you use `Task.WaitAll` to wait on all the tasks to finish.

If you don't use any of these, you can still see the exception by registering to [`TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += (s,e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Exception);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            MultithreadedMethod();
        });
    }

    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    Console.WriteLine(count);
}
```

Yields:

[image: Unobserved task exception]

Note this code still has race-conditions due to the fact we're not actually waiting for any of the results to come, which may not happen after a sleep of 2 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

When I run your code, I see in my Output window:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.SynchronizationLockException' in ConsoleApplication5.exe

I guess you are not capturing the exceptions coming from the tasks (and your IDE isn't set to break when they are unhandled). Instead of sleeping the thread, try this:

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
for (int i = 0; i < 21000; i++)
{
    tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        MultithreadedMethod();
    }));
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

The `WaitAll` will show the exceptions.